# Why can the DLC (data length code) be 0 in CANBUS?

Tags: can

In a lot of document I found out that the DLC can be from 0 to 8, but they don't say what purpose is of DLC being 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of cases where this is of use.

Keepalive. If there is no data that actually needs to be sent but an indication that a node is active.

Trigger. If a node requests a certain type of data from another node, a specific ID is all that is required for a node to then transmit the needed data.

Answer (score 0):

Some CAN frames only need the identifier to act as data. A typical example is the SYNC frame of CANopen which is only sent out as a manner of broadcast clock, to tell nodes to update their outputs at the same time.

There are also RTR frames, which is just a request for data. RTR frames don't have data so DLC should be 0, though I think the standard allows it to be set still, perhaps to request a certain amount of data. Such things would be determined by the higher layer protocol.